# Hall sensor doesn't switch back when I move the magnet away

Tags: sensor, hall-effect

I am currently working with hall sensors and I found this difference between two sensors:

The first one changes voltage when I approach and move back the magnet.

The other one changes when I approach the magnet, but needs the other polarity of the magnet to turn back to its original state (and it has a little circle on the flat side.)

I can't seem to find the keyword in order to make sure the next ones I buy are in the same category as the first one, maybe "latching" is the word I want to avoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are **latching** hall effect sensors.

[Literature from Allegro.](https://www.allegromicro.com/en/Insights-and-Innovations/Technical-Documents/Hall-Effect-Sensor-IC-Publications/Latching-Switch-Hall-Effect-IC-Basics)

Comment: @Neil, you'll notice that Jeroen had to be psychic to answer your question. You need to include part numbers and links to datasheets in your questions.

Comment: @Transistor Yes, my glass ball once more provided the correct answer.